# How to access data in get_context_data RSS Feed django 2.2

Tags: django, django-views, rss, django-rss, django-syndication

I'm trying to access the context dictionary that is returned by a modified 'get_context_data' function in the `LatestVideosFeed` so I can use it in a 'news feed' I'm trying to make because the context that is returned contains the author of the video.
I've been following these docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/syndication/ and I can't figure out how to access the context dictionary that returns from the `get_context_data(self, item, **kwargs):` It works and when I do a debug print just before the return it returns a dictionary with the last entry as the user that uploaded the video. the debug print is `print(context['author'])` which returns as expected everytime the feed is interacted with.

feeds.py

```
class LatestVideosFeed(Feed):
    link = '/video-feeds/'
    description = 'New Video Posts'

    def items(self):
        return VideoPost.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, item, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['author'] = item.author
        print(context['author'])
        return context

    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.title

    def item_description(self, item):
        return item.description

    def item_link(self, item):
        return reverse('video_post', args=[item.pk])
```

views.py

```
def video_list(request):
    feeds = feedparser.parse('http://localhost:8000/profs/video-feeds')
    return render(request, 'vids/video_list.html', {'feeds': feeds})
```

template

```
{% for thing in feeds.entries %}
        <h1>Author</h1><br>
        {{thing.author}} <-- Nothing is printed here
        <h1>Title</h1>
        {{thing.title}}<br>
        <h1>Description</h1>
        {{thing.summary}}<br>
        <h1>Video Link</h1>
        <a href="{{thing.link}}">{{thing.title}}</a><br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your issue is. Where and how do you want to access the context and why?

Comment: I would like to display the author (that's inside the context) in a 'news feed' kind of thing i'm trying to make. I've been accessing the other fields by looping through ```feeds.entries```  where ```feeds = feedparser.parse('http://localhost:8000/profs/video-feeds')```

Comment: Ah, so the question is why is feedparser not returning the custom attribute you have added to your feed?

Comment: Right, sorry about that. I've been programming since I woke up with an hour or so of a break. my brain is fried. Thank you lol

Comment: No worries! Having looked at feedparser it seems to only use instances of [`FeedParserDict`](https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser/blob/develop/feedparser/util.py#L32) which doesn't seem to allow custom attributes

Comment: So I need to use a different parser then? That is so a job for tomorrow lol I'm spent. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read a little bit more into the docs I provided and noticed that the SyndicationFeed allows you to add items, one of the parameters was `author_name`, so I replaced `get_context_data` function with an `item_author_name` function that returned `item.author` and Boom! I accessed it through the `feeds.entries` loop in the template (old and new code below for better context)

```
# Old Code
def get_context_data(self, item, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['author'] = item.author
        print(context['author'])
        return context
```

```
# New Code
def item_author_name(self, item):
        print('Being Called')
        return item.author
```